# R - Collect for loop output into a new column in a dataframe or separate vector?

Tags: r

I've written a function in R that takes a unique identifier (e.g. Q8BZR4) for a mouse protein from a dataframe, matches that to an entry in a dataframe of mouse IDs next to their identical/similar human partner, then returns the human ID. I'll be doing this for hundreds of IDs, so ideally after each human ID was returned if it could be entered either into a new column in the original data frame (data), or into a new vector so I can later add it to the original data frame that would be brilliant.

A subset of the original mouse data and mouse_human partner data:

```
dput(droplevels(df_mouse))
structure(list(Protein.IDs = c("Q8CBM2;A2AL85;Q8BSY0", "A2AMH3;A2AMH5;A2AMH4;Q6X893;Q6X893-2;A2AMH8", 
"A2AMW0;P47757-2;A2AMV7;P47757;F6QJN8;F6YHZ8;F7CAZ6", "Q3U8S1;A2APM5;A2APM3;A2APM4;E9QKM8;Q80X37;A2APM1;A2APM2;P15379-2;P15379-3;P15379-6;P15379-11;P15379-5;P15379-10;P15379-9;P15379-4;P15379-8;P15379-7;P15379;P15379-12;P15379-13", 
"A2ASS6;E9Q8N1;E9Q8K5;A2ASS6-2;A2AT70;F7CR78", "A2AUR7;Q9D031;Q01730"
), Replicate = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Ratio.H.L.normalized.01 = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio.H.L.normalized.02 = c(NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio.H.L.normalized.03 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN)), .Names = c("Protein.IDs", "Replicate", "Ratio.H.L.normalized.01", 
"Ratio.H.L.normalized.02", "Ratio.H.L.normalized.03"), row.names = 12:17, class = "data.frame")

dput(droplevels(df_mouse_human))
structure(list(Human = c("Q8WZ42", "Q8NF91", "Q9UPN3", "Q96RW7", 
"Q8WXG9", "P20929", "Q5T4S7", "O14686", "Q2LD37", "Q92736"), 
    Protein.IDs = c("A2ASS6", "Q6ZWR6", "Q9QXZ0", "D3YXG0", "Q8VHN7", 
    "E9Q1W3", "A2AN08", "Q6PDK2", "A2AAE1", "E9Q401")), .Names = c("Human", 
"Protein.IDs"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code I was working with:

```
  map.ids <- function(row_nums){
  for (ii in 1:length(row_nums)){
  # Picks out the Uniprot Identifer from the data
  row_num = row_nums[ii]
  row_ids <- ((data[row_num,1]))
  # Maps the row IDs to the Human-Mouse set and extracts the Human Identifier
  mouse.id <- which(H.sapiens.M.musculus$Mouse == row_ids)
  human.id <- H.sapiens.M.musculus[mouse.id,1]
  }
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `merge` or `dplyr::join` for this. Would help to see some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `merge` or `dplyr::join` for this task.

Assuming that the first dataframe of mouse IDs, `mouse_data`, looks something like this:

```
mouse_id  value
  O35099 832077
  P97865 839677
  Q9JK95 255605
  P15261 776238
  Q3UGY8 814013
  Q60769 789965
```

And the second dataframe of mouse + human IDs, `mouse_human_data`, looks like this:

```
   mouse_id human_id
     Q8CAF4   Q5SYE7
     Q9WU63   Q9Y5Z4
     Q3UGY8   Q5TH69
     Q9JK95   Q96FX8
     Q60769   P21580
     Q6PFG8   Q7RTU3
     P15261   P15260
     Q80XF5   Q969J5
     Q6PHB0   Q9UHF4
     Q8BGF8   Q5M8T2
     P97865   O00628
     O35099   Q99683
```

Then either:

```
merge(mouse_data, mouse_human_data)
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)
mouse_data %>% 
  left_join(mouse_human_data)
```

will generate this:

```
  mouse_id  value human_id
1   O35099 832077   Q99683
2   P97865 839677   O00628
3   Q9JK95 255605   Q96FX8
4   P15261 776238   P15260
5   Q3UGY8 814013   Q5TH69
6   Q60769 789965   P21580
```

Comment: I used the left_join method as described. Works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to add a command that if the mouse_id has no human_id match it returns the mouse_id? As not all my ids have a corresponding human match.

Comment: Figured out how to do that with coalesce!

Comment: There are other joins, _e.g._ `right_join`, which would return all rows with a mouse match, even if no human match present. Depends how your data looks.

Comment: Hey neilfws, left_join gives the best result, and coalesce brings things together nicely. However there is one caveat I noticed, I added a subset of my data, and the Protein.IDs in df_mouse are usually a string of IDs, which I'm then matching to a single ID in df_mouse_human. Is there a way to make the matching for left_join work for just matching the single ID to any of the IDs in the string? Right now I noticed all the string entries don't get matched.

Comment: For example in the data I added, A2ASS6 of  "A2ASS6;E9Q8N1;E9Q8K5;A2ASS6-2;A2AT70;F7CR78" should match into the df_mouse_human, but currently doesn't unless I trim the data.